# spring transaction how to be created in service method that contain 3 dao method invoke

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

i have a database.xml to define spring transaction like

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice"
            pointcut="execution(* com.compass.utils..*.*(..))" />
</aop:config>
```

and my dao,service are all in the utils package or subpackage
like:

```
com.compass.utils.db.dao
com.compass.utils.service
```

if my service class is like

```
    public class AlarmService {
         @autowired
         private AlarmDao alarmDao;
         @autowired
         private PositionDao positionDao;
         @autowired
         private AccountDao accountDao;
      public void testService(){
          alarmDao.save(a);
          positionDao.save(b);
          accountDao.save(c);
     }
   }
```

how many transactions are created in invoke the testService?
4 transactions?three transactions for save invoke ,and one for testService?or just one transaction?

if 4 transactions are created,how to rollback if save or testService throw exception?
maybe positionDao.save(b) throw exception,just only transaction of positionDao.save rollback,and alarmDao save complete or all save rollback because of testService transaction?

if i change AlarmService  package path ,make it out of com.compass.utils,like
com.compass.service,what effect the transactions about my question?

when AlarmService  is in com.compass.service package,and i annotation @Transactional in testService method, what effect the transactions about my question?

@Transactional can @Override the database.xml configure?

thanks for your help and suggestion in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how many transactions are created in invoke the testService? 4 transactions?three transactions

Only one TX will be created and if any exception occurs in one of the save methods, the TX will be rolled back.

> if i change AlarmService package path ,make it out of com.compass.utils,like com.compass.service,what effect the transactions about my question?

3 TXs will be created and each one will be committed or rolled back individually.

> when AlarmService is in com.compass.service package,and i annotation @Transactional in testService method, what effect the transactions about my question?

None, since it is not in configured packages, Spring does not advise that, so your annotation will be ignored. This will behave like the second question and will create 3 transactions.

> @Transactional can @Override the database.xml configure?

Yes, Spring is capable of using XML and annotation configurations alongside together and always uses the most specific configuration which is the annotation in this case.

P.S. You can change all these with different [propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) levels. These are all based on default behavior.

Comment: thanks very much ,and your first question answer Only one TX will be created,is from the document?or some other reference?

Comment: This is how `REQUIRED` propagation works which is the default.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED

Comment: yes,but after the first alarmDao.save(a);why the transaction not closed?if it closed,none transaction exists,why not create a new one?because the testService method?

Comment: When manager sees a method with `REQUIRED` attribute, if there is a TX running in the context, it uses the same TX, otherwise creates a new TX and associates it with the method. In your example, `testService` is the entry point, so manager creates a TX for it; later when calling `alarmDao.save`, because a TX exists, manager uses the existing one without creating another one. Also manager is smart enough to close the TX when the creator method (`testService` in this case) finishes not when other dao methods finish.